# Use HTML to move or copy a file

Tags: html, file, transfer

I am using a HTML web-page, i don't want to use PHP coding.
I am trying to find some code that will allow me to upload a file and place it in a specified directory. How would i do that.

input type="file", allows me to specify a file but what code allows me to move or copy that file to another location.

Comment: If you want to upload a file you'll need a server-side script. It doesn't have to be PHP, but you'll need more than just HTML.

Comment: You need to submit the form to a script on the server that will read and store the file. This is unavoidable.

Comment: :D Please read more about HTML. You need server-side-program to do that. e.g. PHP (most popular), Perl, C ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's impossible to oparte on upload file without server-side technology (like php), sorry...

Comment: I thaught that there was some code that could be entered that would allow me to at least transfer a file to a server, but thanks anyway

Comment: Any server-side code should be capable of handling an upload. Certainly ASP.NET can do it - no PHP required.

Comment: I dont have anything server-side, its just webspace